# Unable to read an excel file using pandas to retrieve the desired output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my input and I want to read it in such a way that they get categorized in three categories- technical, functional, soft
[image]

desired output
[image]

I am not able to get the logic to the output.

Comment: my gut tells me that `pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays()` might help here

Comment: I am looking for some logic @JonSG

Answer (score 0):

Using .assign() and .apply():

```
emp_id = df["Unnamed: 0"][1]

df = (df
      .head(1)
      .assign(Technical=lambda x: x[[x for x in df.columns if "Technical" in x]]
              .apply(lambda row: ", ".join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1))
      .assign(EmpID=emp_id)
      )
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains(r"\d")]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                        Technical       Functional                 Soft  EmpID
0  E-mail Writing, Angular/Flask, MongoDB, Python  Problem solving  VerbalCommunication  A4593
```

Comment: This is reading only my first line of csv not the entire csv file @jason baker